# How to change whole activity bg image from fragment?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating an app. I'm just a beginner. I have a doubt. I would like to know how to change the whole activity background image from a fragment.

Comment: What did you except. If you are in fragment your UI is fragment layout. If you want to change UI background of your fragment add drawable as background to your rootlayout(Eg:ConstrainLayout,Linearlayout..etc).

Comment: I have MainActivity with navigation drawer with few items and bottom navigation with 3 items. Created fragments to navigate through the items. Im in one fragment which has a switch and when I turn on the switch it should change the background of the MainActivity. I used DrawerLayout for the MainActivity.

Comment: One Q: If your activity layout changed to fragment UI then your view totally covered by fragments then y you need to change activity background.

Comment: Oh my god... You just opened my eyes.... Thank you so much sir... I got it... really Thank You... :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a fragment first of all you have to take a reference to the activity and then you can change its layout in this way:

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.yournewlayout);
```

Comment: Sir, I don't want to change the layout but the layout's background image. I have used DrawerLayout.

Comment: sir I've been trying to post my code but I'm not sure of it since I'm new to this. Could you please help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: Sir, I got it. Thank you so much for your help... but i have one more dbt. The switch in one fragment,say settingsFragment - is turned on it is not retaining navigate to other fragments and return to this setingsFragment ie it is turning off byitself.. what to do?

Comment: @EunHye can you take a screenshot of what you are talking about?

Comment: nightSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                if(isChecked){                    frameLayout.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nightmode3));
dayOrNight.setText("on");
nightSwitch.setChecked(true);
                }
                else{                    frameLayout.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.daymode3));
dayOrNight.setText("off");
                } } });

Comment: I'm so sorry I couldnt post the code properly i just pasted in the comment... sorry...